# Volume pine script v4

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to compose a code that will display a label above the bar, the volume of which is 20% larger than the previous volume. I've tried these solutions:

```
a = volume / volume [1]
if a> = 1
     label.new (int (a), close, text = "LONG", color = color.red, style = label.style_xcross, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
```

And this

```
max_bars_back (time, 100)
a = volume [1] * 100 / volume
if a> = 2
     label.new (int (a), close, text = "LONG", color = color.red, style = label.style_xcross, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
```

And like this:

```
a = volume [1] * 100 / volume
if a> = 2
     label.new (int (a), close, text = "LONG", color = color.red, style = label.style_xcross, textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> help me compose a code that will display a label above the bar, the volume of which is 20% larger than the previous volume, I tried to do this

Try this simple script, it should draw label by your condition:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
// volume
if volume > volume[1] * 1.2
    label.new(bar_index, high, "V > V[1] more than 1.2 times\n current volume is " + tostring(volume) + "\nprevious volume is " + tostring(volume[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. can I contact you via telegram for advice? I will pay you at USDT
I hope you speak Russian?

Comment: @Stock, you did not add any contact details into your profile. How do you expect Artem to contact you? :-) . and you could bump Artem's reputation at SO by  clicking up arrow :-)

Comment: My telegram @ efefefef22